# Drop view if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, create-view

I have script where I want to first drop view and then create it.
I know how to drop table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1' AND type = 'U') DROP TABLE table1;
```

so I did the same for views:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'view1' AND type = 'U') DROP VIEW view1;
create view1 as(......)
```

and then I got error:

> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: place a `GO` between these commands...

Comment: I put it before create: Go Create....etc but then got: There is already an object named 'TSB' in the database.

Comment: Wrong object type - use 'V' instead of 'U'. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Comment: yes, changed and it's working

Answer (score 125, accepted):

your exists syntax is wrong and you should seperate DDL with go like below

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.views where name='tst' and type='v')
drop view tst;
go

create view tst
as
select * from test
```

you also can check existence test, with object_id like below

```
if object_id('tst','v') is not null
drop view tst;
go

create view tst
as
select * from test
```

In SQL 2016,you can use below syntax to drop

```
Drop view  if exists dbo.tst
```

From SQL2016 CU1,you can do below

```
create or alter view vwTest
as
 select 1 as col;
go
```

Comment: thanks, change U to V and now is working! thanks for help

Comment: Minor correction- DROP VIEW dbo.tst IF EXISTS should read DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.tst

Comment: thanks, I actually had a semicolon behind the go after drop and it didnt like that. Removed the semicolon and it worked perfectly.

Comment: how do i add the schema to the check?

Answer (score 5):

```
DROP VIEW if exists {ViewName}
Go
CREATE View {ViewName} AS 
SELECT * from {TableName}  
Go
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the error

> `'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.`

Microsoft SQL Server has a quirky reqirement that `CREATE VIEW` be the *only* statement in a batch. This is also true of a few other statements, such as `CREATE FUNCTION`. It is *not* true of `CREATE TABLE`, so go figure …

The solution is to send your script to the server in small batches. One way to do this is to select a single statement and execute it. This is clearly inconvenient.

The more convenient solution is to get the client to send the script in small isolated batches.

The `GO` keyword is not strictly an SQL command, which is why you can’t end it with a semicolon like real SQL commands. Instead it is an instruction to the client to break the script at this point and to send the portion as a batch.

As a result, you end up writing something like:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS … ;
GO
CREATE VIEW … AS … ;
GO
```

None of the other database servers I have encountered (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQLite) have this quirk, so the requirement appears to be Microsoft Only.

Answer (score 2):

To cater for the schema as well, use this format in SQL 2014

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.views V inner join sys.[schemas] S on  v.schema_id = s.schema_id where s.name='dbo' and v.name = 'someviewname' and v.type = 'v')
  drop view [dbo].[someviewname];
go
```

And just throwing it out there, to do stored procedures, because I needed that too:

```
if exists(select 1
          from sys.procedures p
          inner join sys.[schemas] S on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
          where
              s.name='dbo' and p.name = 'someprocname'
          and p.type in ('p', 'pc')
  drop procedure [dbo].[someprocname];
go
```